# CoreData mapping with JSON array with RestKit 0.20?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a `JSON` as follows

```
{
    "code":0,
    "response":{
        "Cirqit":{
            "Cirqit":{...},
            "Owner":{...},
            "CirqitMembers":[
                {
                    "User":{...},
                    "CirqitMember":{...}
                },
                {
                    "User":{...},
                    "CirqitMember":{...}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My mapping Code is below:

```
   //User mapping
    RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:apiInterface.managedObjectStore];
    NSDictionary *userMappingDict = @{@"id": @"id",@"firstname": @"firstname"};
    [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userMappingDict];

    //Member Status Mapping
    RKEntityMapping *membStatusMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MemberStatusInfo" inManagedObjectStore:apiInterface.managedObjectStore];
    NSDictionary *membStatusMappingDict = @{@"id": @"id",@"user_id": @"user_id"};    [membStatusMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:membStatusMappingDict];

    //Cirqit Member Mapping
    RKEntityMapping *membMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CirqitMember" inManagedObjectStore:apiInterface.managedObjectStore];
    NSDictionary *membMappingDict = @{ @"CirqitMember.id":@"id" };
    [membMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:membMappingDict];
    [membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.User" toKeyPath:@"memberStatus" withMapping:userMapping]];
    [membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.CirqitMember" toKeyPath:@"memberDetails" withMapping:membStatusMapping]];
    membMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

    //Cirqit Mapping
    RKEntityMapping *cirqitMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Cirqit" inManagedObjectStore:apiInterface.managedObjectStore];
    NSDictionary *cirqitMappingDict = @{   @"response.Cirqit.Cirqit.id":@"id",
                                 @"response.Cirqit.Cirqit.allow_invite": @"allow_invite"};    
    [cirqitMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:cirqitMappingDict];
    [cirqitMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers" toKeyPath:@"cirqitMembers" withMapping:membMapping]];
    cirqitMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:cirqitMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];
    operation = [apiInterface getOperationWithRequest:request forResponseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
    [operation start];
```

Here membMapping,cirqitMapping works fine. but membStatusMapping,userMapping is not working. Actually there is no mapping error but mapping is not occured.

My Managed object class below:

```
@interface CirqitMember : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MemberStatusInfo *memberDetails;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *memberStatus;

@end
```

Comment: Do you have a mapping that isn't working? What's it doing wrong? Show what you have.

Comment: RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];     [membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.User" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:userMapping]];

Comment: since the object inside JSON array, is there any problem. all other mapping works fine except this.

Comment: Your `userMapping` doesn't show any mappings being set... Also, supply all of the mappings and the response descriptors if you want real help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're adding the relationship mappings, the key paths in the mappings should be relative to the container, not relative to the root. Currently you have:

```
[membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.User" toKeyPath:@"memberStatus" withMapping:userMapping]];
[membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.CirqitMember" toKeyPath:@"memberDetails" withMapping:membStatusMapping]];
```

Change that to:

```
[membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"User" toKeyPath:@"memberStatus" withMapping:userMapping]];
[membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"CirqitMember" toKeyPath:@"memberDetails" withMapping:membStatusMapping]];
```

This should also apply to:

```
[cirqitMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers" toKeyPath:@"cirqitMembers" withMapping:membMapping]];
```

But that one probably works because of the structure of the JSON...

Comment: Thank you alot...[membMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.CirqitMember" toKeyPath:@"memberDetails" withMapping:membStatusMapping]]; still not mapping. might be my logical error. i will look on that.

Comment: The keypath in you comment is still `@"response.Cirqit.CirqitMembers.CirqitMember"`. It doesn't need all of the keypath elements that are already handled in `cirqitMapping`.

Comment: Sorry, i had corrected it in my praogram as @"CirqitMember". but still not working.. this only rest all works very fine.

Comment: Looks like the mapping dictionaries have a similar issue with using the full key path.

Comment: i found out the problem. 'addPropertyMapping' will work only for one 'RKRelationshipMapping'. Which one i give first, it work fine.